# extract-text-webpack-plugin not extracting css

Tags: css, webpack

When I created chunk with the help of CommonChunkPlugin, extract-text-webpack-plugin doesn`t extract css from landings chunk. Any ideas?

```
config: {
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        chunks: [
            'vzr',
            'vzrProduct',
            'emptyProduct'
        ],
        async: 'landings'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
        allChunks: true
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `plugins: [ ... ]` instead of `plugins: { ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the function into minChunk and problem is solved. CommonChunkPlugin stopped to extract css and less modules

```
config: {
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        chunks: [
            'kaskoLanding',
            'kaskoLandingProduct',
            'kaskoCalculator',
            'kaskoCalculatorProduct',
            'osagoCalculator',
            'osagoCalculatorProduct',
            'vzr',
            'vzrProduct',
            'emptyProduct'
        ],
        minChunks: (module, count) => {
            if (module.resource && (/^.*(css|less)$/).test(module.resource)){
                return false;
            }

            return count >= 9;
        },
        async: 'landings'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
        allChunks: true
    })
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `Objects` must have a `key` and `value` separated by a colon. In your case, you have `plugins: {}` and inserting to this a series of functions, which we may call `keys`, but that are not followed by a colon and a `value` but a comma.

According to [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/) `plugins` are not an `object` but an `array` of values.
So, instead of:

```
config: {
  plugins: {
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      chunks: [
        'vzr',
        'vzrProduct',
        'emptyProduct'
      ],
      async: 'landings'
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
    allChunks: true
  })
}
```

}

Rather:

```
config: {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      chunks: [
        'vzr',
        'vzrProduct',
        'emptyProduct'
      ],
      async: 'landings'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post it as an answer so that somebody else who runs into the same problem may get help